# What is the fully qualified namespace for an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to call a method on a model from within a gem. Therefore I need to know the fully qualified name for a model, from ::Rails on down... Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a namespace around ActiveRecord models loaded into a Rails project unless you explicitly declare one.

For example, if you have a User model it will not be namespaced unless declared as such.

Comment: Turned out I entered a plural name when doing rails g model. That was the problem, which I incorrectly diagnosed as a namespacing error.

Comment: Easy to do, one of my most common Rails typos too.